# Pie Radar Chart outline series not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have been trying to create a Pie Radar Chart as described in answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/687036/how-to-make-a-pie-radar-chart).

Everything works until I get to the section that describes inserting a series to create the chart's outline:

> To get the radial segment borders we need to add a new series. Set the
>   title to be cell C1 ("Sector Weight") and the values to the rows in
>   column C (C2:C9). Set the horizontal category axis labels to be your
>   chart labels (G2:G9).
>
> Change the chart type for this new series to a pie chart. Remove the
>   fill for the pie segments and add black borders. Add data labels for
>   the pie series, selecting the Category Name instead of Value and
>   setting the position to Outside End.

My problem is, when right click on the `Chart > Select Data > Add New Series` (as described above) and then change the Horizontal Category Axis Labels to the Chart Labels and click OK-there is no visible change to the chart.

I went to `Chart Tools > Layout` and added the Legend back in to see if `Sector Weight` showed up, and the legend does indeed show it.  But, I can't click on it anywhere on the chart to change the series to a Pie Chart. If I change the whole chart (i.e. all series) to a Pie Chart then I get nothing that looks like the final chart in the tutorial with the sector borders.

Comment: Please continue on your original post as there is no continuity in your query and its obvious that you are extending from some other post or rectify your current post to be complete

Comment: Hi Gaurav, many thanks for letting me know and sorry about this - I am a completely new user. This is the original query I was trying to link to: http://superuser.com/questions/687036/how-to-make-a-pie-radar-chart

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed all of the directions in the original question's answer, and everything looks good until the point you've mentioned above, I think you're just not selecting the new `Sector Weight` series when you try to reformat (I recreated the Chart and had trouble getting the selection right).

1. Once you've added the `Sector Weight` series, go to Format tab on your Excel ribbon.
2. On the top left (in the Current Selection section), there should be a drop-down selection box for the chart components.  Use this drop down to select your `Sector Weight` series.
   On your chart, you should see a small selection handle show up, near the middle of the chart. This is the new series you added.

[image: New Series]

3. Right-click, while your cursor is over this spot and choose Change Series Chart Type.  Now, it should look like an 8 piece Pie Chart.
4. Use the drop down selection box and re-select your series.
5. Choose Format Selection, then change Fill to None, and you should have the chart as described in the original answer.

Comment: By answering this question, I am in no way recommending the use of a Pie Radar Chart.  There are probably many other ways to display the same information in an easier to create and more effective manner.