# How do I insert another segment into the radar pie chart that is shown on this site?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I came across [this tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/687036/how-to-make-a-pie-radar-chart) for creating a radar pie chart, and let me say it is fantastic!  The problem I'm having is that I need the chart to contain 10 or even 12 segments, but I cannot figure out how to add additional categories into the data sheet and have them respond the way they're supposed to in the chart.  There's got to be a way to copy/paste, and then reconfigure some of the formulas in the copied cells.  But I'm not sure what adjustments need to be made.

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried? This looks easy: there is a workbook region with 8 data rows. What happens when you add rows to that region?

Comment: Hi G-man.  I have successfully added the rows.  And the new pie segments appear just fine, with the correct labels and such.  But the problem is that that the pie segments do no respond to a change in the value and "fill in" like they're supposed to.  No matter what I change the value to, the pie segment remains empty.  If you're so inclined, [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/mz5xn4) is a sendspace link to the actual file I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you posted, the tutorial starts out with 8 data rows.

You want 10 or 12, so start out with 10 or 12 and follow the steps.

It should not really matter how many rows of data you start with. You just need to adjust the ranges in the formulas to cover the ranges that you use.

Comment: Thanks tevlyn.  I'm unable to start from scratch and reproduce the chart following the steps.  I spent way too much time trying that and it didn't work.  However I am able to add new categories and get the slices to look the way they should.  However the segments of the chart do not fill in when I adjust the value column for any of the new rows I've created.  I can get the angles correct, segment weight, labels, etc.  But the color function doesn't work.

Can you tell me where I might find that setting?  I wonder if I just need to choose the color for the new segments somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the chart and go to select data you need to add the new data from the lines you added so point two on the chart the series name is `=CHART!$G$2` and the series values are `=CHART!$H$2:$ND$2` you just need to change it to `=CHART!$G$12` and `=CHART!$H$12:$ND$12` for the new point 12 on your chart and do this for each new one you add so 9, 10, 11, 12 (like example), 13, 14 etc...